# how to extract a pattern from a txt file in Talend

Tags: talend, txt

I have a txt file as the following and  I would like to extract the Accession ID "GSE????" or "GSE** " with Talend, I tried the "tPatternextract" and it seems not to work in Talend 7.1, is there a way to extract all text with a pattern?
Best,
Xinhui

1. Integrated analysis of DNA methylation and gene expression profiles identified S100A9 as a potential biomarker in ulcerative colitis
   (Submitter supplied) In this research,  90 differential expression mRNAs (DEMs).
   Organism:   Homo sapiens
   Type:       Expression profiling by array; Non-coding RNA profiling by array
   Platform: GPL20115 6 Samples
   FTP download: GEO (TXT) ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE160nnn/GSE160804/
   Series      Accession: GSE160804    ID: 200160804
2. Induced organoids derived from patients with ulcerative colitis recapitulate the colitic reactivity
   (Submitter supplied) We report the application of single nucleus RNA-seq.
   Organism:   Homo sapiens
   Type:       Expression profiling by high throughput sequencing
   Platform: GPL24676 11 Samples
   FTP download: GEO (MTX, TSV) ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE152nnn/GSE152999/
   SRA Run Selector: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/study/?acc=PRJNA641142
   Series      Accession: GSE152999    ID: 200152999

Answer (score 0):

Use a `tFilterRow`

[image]

In the Component tab, click on "Use advanced mode" and give this condition

```
input_row.columnName1.startsWith("AA12")
```

Comment: Shall I read the txt file with tFileInputDelimited in this case?

Comment: You have changed your question a lot ...  Assuming that the each item is on one line, then the condition  `input_row.columnname1.contains("Series Accession: GSE")` will extract the relevant lines. Yes,  the input is `tFileInputDelimited` (just give a non existant field delimiter like "!!" so each row is considered as 1 field) and you send the output of the `tFilterRow` to a `tFileOutputDelimited` to create a new file for example.

Comment: hi, thanks! when I continue to work on it. I used the condition as the following: input_row.Column0.contains("Series"), here Column0 is the first column. Unfortunately, it does not work. :(, do you have some suggestion